# How do I redirect the output from a bash script to stderr

Tags: linux, bash

I've written a bash script. It has a few echo statements. It invokes a few 3rd party tools.  I would like to redirect everything that goes to stdout (from my echo statements and all the tools output) to stderr.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

You need to redirect the stdout of the command to stderr.

`your_command.sh 1>&2`

If you want to do this from within the script, you can wrap your whole script into one function and redirect its output to stderr:

```
main() {
   echo hello
   echo world
   some_script.sh
}

main 1>&2
```

Comment: So something like?  echo hello 1>&2   Also, is this the same as (>&2 echo hello)

Comment: @PhilO Yes, redirection operators can appear (almost) anywhere in the command line, as the shell identifies and removes them before calling the command. They can precede the name of a simple command, as in your example, but they must appear after compound commands like `while`, `for`, `if`, etc. `echo 1>&2 hello` would also work the same.

Answer (score 3):

```
exec >&2
```

Put that at the top of your script to redirect all future output to stderr.

```
$ help exec
exec: exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments ...]] [redirection ...]
    Replace the shell with the given command.

    Execute COMMAND, replacing this shell with the specified program.
    ARGUMENTS become the arguments to COMMAND.  If COMMAND is not specified,
    any redirections take effect in the current shell.
```

Comment: Simple!  Suppose I want output to go to both stdout and stderr?

Comment: this doesn't redirect output from tools

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me was to enclose the text of the script within ()'s and redirect stdout to stderr like so:
`(
echo 1
echo 2
tool1 
) 1>&2`

Comment: Try it with curlies. `{ ... } >&2`